# How is momentum conserved in pair production?

Tags: momentum, conservation-laws, pair-production

I saw today in book that the momentum in pair production is conserved.

My question is, how could it be possible that the momentum is conserved?

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pair_production#Photon_to_electron_and_positron): “The photon must be near a nucleus in order to satisfy conservation of momentum, as an electron–positron pair produced in free space cannot both satisfy conservation of energy and momentum.”

Answer (score 2):

It seems that your intuition is saying that it's not possible for a gamma ray to turn into a pair of particles without some additional mechanism to balance the energy and momentum equations, and your intuition is right.  Real pair production from a gamma ray always involves another particle such as a heavy nucleus.

Comment: Or just another gamma ray (which might as well come from a nucleus)

Comment: Except that gamma ray - gamma ray interactions have a *very* low cross section.  "*Very*" is an understatement.

Comment: pair producing $\gamma$'s like the large $Z^2$ of a heavy nucleus, but the heavy part is not important, for $\hbar\omega > 4m_ec^2$. At that threshold, pair production in the fields of atomic electrons also occurs. See: http://rcwww.kek.jp/research/shield/photon_r.pdf